# Как сделать округление до того знака, когда попадается первая цифра больше "0"?

Tags: python, округление

Есть числа меньше единицы, например:

```
0.00084689,    
0.0000642385
```

Как написать метод округления, чтобы округление происходило до того знака, когда попадается первая цифра больше "0", чтобы в итоге получить:

```
0.0008    
0.00006
```

Comment: Если не обрезать, а округлять, то можно `print(format('%.1g' % 0.000362))` (в данном случае будет 0.0004)

Comment: @MBo Большое спасибо!

Comment: @MBo, что-то не срабатывает `print(format('%.1g' % 0.0000362))` --> '4e-05'

Comment: @SergFSM Да, для больших и малых порядков g-формат действительно сам выбирает научную e-нотацию

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю пройтись по `str(num)` и определить НЕ 0, тогда и посчитать, на каком она месте, после чего через `round(num, no_null)` сделать округление

Comment: `str(0.0000642385)` --> '6.42385e-05'

Answer (score 0):

Такую штуку удобно делать через регулярные выражения.  Преобразуем число в строку, находим вначале все нули по максимуму, определяем их количество и обрезаем строку до нужной длины. Затем конвертируем обратно в число

Пример на Python:

```
import re

def my_round(num):
    to_string = "{:.100f}".format(num)   # comvert to string
    result = re.match(r'0\.0+', to_string)   # finde pattern 0.000...
    sero_list_len = len(result.group(0)) # get length of zero list
    cuted_string = to_string[:sero_list_len+1] # cut string
    return float(cuted_string) # convert to float

num = 0.00084689  
print (my_round(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте потестировать такую регулярку:

```
from re import sub

num = 0.0000056006000288

res = sub(r'([1-9]\d)(\d)*$',lambda m: str(round(int(m[1])/10)), f'{num:.10f}')

print(res)  # '0.000006'
```